# Is Manual of Buddhism by Hardy Spence ,a good book to study Buddhism?

Tags: academic-buddhism

I have found hard to get stories and teachings of Buddha in the book [Manual of Buddhism](https://archive.org/details/manualofbudhism00hard) by Hardy Spence.

Is Manual of Buddhism by Hardy Spence, a good book to study Buddhism?

Comment: Are you asking for a list of recommended, free, modern, English-language texts to study Buddhism? Or do you prefer to ask, specifically, about that one book by Hardy Spence? I mean, I don't know that book. It was published in 1853. You previously asked [this question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/21866/254). Is that because you're especially interested in 19th century texts, or is it because you're looking for free texts?

Comment: I am asking specifically about the book Manual of Buddhism by Hardy Spence. I find this book very interesting and would like to develop my knowledge of Buddhism based on it.

Answer (score 1):

Though I'm not familiar with that book, it's clear that the best books from which to learn about Buddhism in English have all been written within the past 40 years. The Dharma has taken root in the West, and you can learn from Western Buddhist masters fluent in Western culture, which makes their words easier to understand.

Comment: OK. Can you name a book which is available on Kindle ?

Comment: There are many excellent books available on Kindle. Some are quite inexpensive, by  Thich Nhat Hanh.  I'm not sure how many you can available for free, though there is much free information about all aspects of Buddhism available online, and that includes many excellent talks on YouTube.